# Update Created, Created By, Modified, Modified By using CSOM

Tags: list, csom, updatelistitems

How to update Created, Created By, Modified and Modified By in list items using CSOM?

Comment: You can achieve similar functionality Using REST API. I have tested in for Sharepoint Online. You can find code snippet at [Update Editor and Author Filed](https://anomepani.github.io/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please find the code to update Created, Created By, Modified, Modified By using CSOM.

```
            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://siteURL/");
            List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Info Path");
            ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
            ctx.Load(items); // loading all the fields
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            User theUser = ctx.Web.EnsureUser("domain\\user");
            ctx.Load(theUser);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                item["Created"] = "2015-07-03";
                item["Modified"] = "2017-07-03";
                item["Editor"] = theUser;
                item["Author"] = theUser;
                item.Update(); //Apply the change
            }
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: i too agree with the code given above, but it adds an version to the item if we update the system columns

Comment: I couldn't make it work. As soon as ExecuteQuery is executed, the "Created" / "Modified" values revert to their previous values. On another hand, the versioning can be suppressed using List.EnableVersioning (followed by List.Update and ClientContext.ExecuteQuery).

Comment: You can avoid the extra versions by using `item.SystemUpdate()` instead of `item.Update()` - this may not have been available in CSOM when the question was raised (can't remember when it was added).