# Editor and Author not changing to custom user value

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

CSOM when trying to copy the editor and author who created a list item in a different list while copying items between lists. The Author and Editor are showing as my name instead of the copied user id. It was working fine with a person/group column but giving me unexpected result with editor and author columns.

```
FieldUserValue fuv1 = (FieldUserValue)SourcelistItem["Author"];
                        string loginName1 = LookupLoginNameInUserInfoList(SourceclientContext, fuv1.LookupId);
                        DestnewItem["Author"] = GetUserId(contextDestination, loginName1);

                        FieldUserValue fuv2 = (FieldUserValue)SourcelistItem["Editor"];
                        string loginName2 = LookupLoginNameInUserInfoList(SourceclientContext, fuv2.LookupId);
//Both Author and Editor fail to write the user ID that it gets from the other list author column value.
                        DestnewItem["Editor"] = GetUserId(contextDestination, loginName2);
//Email Person logic - Works Fine, writes the user from another list as they are.
                        FieldUserValue fuv = (FieldUserValue)SourcelistItem["Email"];
                        string loginName = LookupLoginNameInUserInfoList(SourceclientContext, fuv.LookupId);
                        DestnewItem["Email"] = GetUserId(contextDestination, loginName);


 // helper method to lookup a user in the user info list
    static string LookupLoginNameInUserInfoList(ClientContext context, int lookupId)
    {
        var username = string.Empty;

        var userInfoList = context.Web.SiteUserInfoList;
        context.Load(userInfoList);

        ListItem item = userInfoList.GetItemById(lookupId);
        context.Load(item);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        string loginName = item["Name"] as string;
        context.Dispose();
        return loginName;
    }

    static FieldUserValue GetUserId(ClientContext contextDestination,String loginName)
    {
        Web web2 = contextDestination.Web;
        User newUser = web2.EnsureUser(loginName);
        contextDestination.Load(newUser);
        contextDestination.ExecuteQuery();
        //Need to pass ID instead of user
        FieldUserValue newValue = new FieldUserValue();
        newValue.LookupId = newUser.Id;
        contextDestination.Dispose();
        return newValue;
    }
```

Comment: Check this question (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220173/update-created-created-by-modified-modified-by-using-csom)

Comment: have you followed [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220173/update-created-created-by-modified-modified-by-using-csom)? Try using `DestnewItem.SystemUpdate()` instead of `DestnewItem.Update()`. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap tried your way, it is not copying the list item if I change from Update to System Update. It gives me item cannot be updated in the current state of the object.

Comment: @JefinMathew tried to pass User instead of fieldUserValue Id, didn't work either. It was creating with my name even though I can see that it is getting the login name of the selected user.